# How to use star in table row for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tablerow

```
if ([stararray count] > 0) {
        for (int i = 0;i < [stararray count]; i++) {
            NSString *starstr =[stararray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSInteger starinteger = [starstr integerValue];
           btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:kLabelRect2];
            btn.tag =starinteger - 1;
            NSLog(@"btnID1:%d",btn.tag);
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(starClicked:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
            btn.hidden = inPseudoEditMode;
        }

        for (int i = 0;i < [nostararray count]; i++) {
        NSString *starstr =[nostararray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSInteger starinteger = [starstr integerValue];
        btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:kLabelRect2];
            btn.tag =starinteger - 1;
            NSLog(@"btnID2:%d",btn.tag);
           [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(starClicked:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                                    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
btn.hidden = inPseudoEditMode;
        }

        //stararray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    else {
        btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:kLabelRect2];
        btn.tag =indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"btnID2:%d",btn.tag);
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(starClicked:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
        btn.hidden = inPseudoEditMode;
    }
```

Comment: if there are two rows then when user clicks on first button on first row then change takes place in second button. please find some solution

Comment: can you post your latest code?

Comment: have a look at question that is the latest code

Comment: @7KV7 hey i am facing issue in changing button image depending on the integer value from database. 
1 for star image
0 for dot image

HAVE A LOOK AT CODE IN QUESTION. this if and else loop are inside cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize your `UITableViewCell` to have a button which when clicked performs ur necessary action

**Update**

```
  -(void)starClicked:(id)sender 
    {

        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        NSLog(@"btnID:%d",button.tag);
        if(button.tag == initialTag) {
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal]];
            button.tag = newTag;
        }
        else if(button.tag == newTag)
        {
           [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal]];
           button.tag = initialTag;
        }

        NSLog(@"btnID:%d",btn.tag);

    }
```

**Another Option**

```
-(void)starClicked:(id)sender 
{

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
button.selected = !button.selected; // toggle the selected property, 

    if (button.selected)
    {

// code to change image for selected state. 
    }
    else
    {
// code to change image for normal state. 
    }
}
```

Comment: @7KV7 Hey how do i bring back dot.png on clicking on button which has image name star.png

Comment: See the updated answer. The initialTag is the tag when u have the dot image and the newTag is when u have the star image

Comment: hey i am not getting initial tag and new tag please explain

Comment: initialtag is the tag u have for the button when u have the dot image and newtag is the one if the button has star image

Comment: Its like a switch action through a button.

Comment: should i hardcore the values of initial tag and new tag?

Comment: I think they are set as 0 by default so you can try 0 in place of initialTag and 1 in place of newTag

Comment: yes done the same but it is giving issue for button on third row i.e button with tag 2. its not getting change for button with tag 2

Comment: the buttons have tag initially other than 0 just nslog them and see what the button tags are initially when u click the button

Comment: I think the buttons have tags like 0,1,2,3 etc. so u have to set newTag as different from those

Comment: when i click button with tag 2 it is not going into if loop as it is not equal to 0. I suppose we cant hardcore it

Comment: remove the conditions for now and just see the tags for each button and then set the tag for dot and star images accordingly

Comment: Or you can also make use of selected property of button to change image accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `UIButton` to your table cells , which will toggle when user press them.

```
-(void) toggleStarButton:(id)sender
{
    if([sender tag]== 0)
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTag:1];


    else if([sender tag]==1)
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unStar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTag:0];

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey but its giving an issue in selection of button

Comment: @7KV7 if there are two rows then when user clicks on first button on first row then change takes place in second button. please find some solution